# Common Lisp Loop

Tags: loops, common-lisp

In the following loop:

```
(let ((funs (loop for i upto 3 do (print i) collect #'(lambda () i))))
  (loop for fun in funs collect (funcall fun)))
```

i would intuitively think i would get a list of four closures which return the numbers 0 1 2 and 3 upon being called, but this is what i get:

```
>> 0 
>> 1 
>> 2 
>> 3
=> (4 4 4 4)
```

But rebinding the `i` locally to something else:

```
(let ((funs (loop for i upto 3 do (print i) collect (let ((x i))
                          #'(lambda () x)))))
  (loop for fun in funs collect (funcall fun)))
```

works as expected:

```
>> 0 
>> 1 
>> 2 
>> 3
=> (0 1 2 3)
```

So each of the functions return 4, why are all return values the same, and why 4?

**update**

This seems to be a question about lambda actually. See below:

```
(setq dynamic-var 8
  funs ())
(push (lambda () dynamic-var) funs)
(incf dynamic-var)
(push (lambda () dynamic-var) funs)
(mapcar #'funcall funs)         ;(9 9)
```

Comment: in fact, that is not really common-lisp specific question. For example, here is one of the most popular questions for javascript job interviews: what would be the output of the following code `var fns = []; for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { fns.push(() => i) }; fns.map(it => it())`

Comment: Great example! It helped me have a better understanding of the problem. My misunderstanding was that i was thinking by pushing a new function to some lists (`fns`) i am taking a snapshot from the state of the iteration variable (`i`). This holds also in Python: `[fn() for fn in [lambda: i for i in range(5)]]` gives: `[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]`.

Comment: @student: that's right. if we want to make a snapshot, we have to do it explicitly (by another LET binding for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What does

```
(let (i      ; a counter variable
      f)     ; a list of functions
  (setf i 1)
  (push (lambda () i) f)
  (setf i 2)
  (push (lambda () i) f)

  (mapcar #'funcall f))
```

return?

How about:

```
(let (i
      f)
  (setf i 1)
  (push (lambda () i) f)
  (let (i)
    (setf i 2)
    (push (lambda () i) f))

  (mapcar #'funcall f))
```

Which is the `LOOP` model?

See also:

```
CL-USER 42 > (let (f)
               (dotimes (i 10 (mapcar #'funcall (reverse f)))
                 (push (lambda () i) f)))
(10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10)

CL-USER 43 > (let (f)
               (dotimes (i 10 (mapcar #'funcall (reverse f)))
                 (push (let ((i i))
                         (lambda () i))
                       f)))
(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

The Common Lisp standard says for `DOTIMES`:

> It is implementation-dependent whether dotimes establishes a new binding of var on each iteration or whether it establishes a binding for var once at the beginning and then assigns it on any subsequent iterations.

you write:

> i would intuitively think i would get a list of four closures which return the numbers 0 1 2 and 3 upon being called

This intuition is only partly correct. You get four closures, but in this case they all share one variable binding. Thus they can only see the current binding of this one variable. In Common Lisp this binding is mutable and closures see the current binding, not the one of the initial binding of closure creation time.

Your intuition would be right, when each closure had its own variable binding.

**Additional answer: why is this Lisp returning 10 ?**

```
(PROGN
  (SETQ I (THE INTEGER (1+ (THE INTEGER I))))
  (WHEN (>= (THE INTEGER I)
            (THE INTEGER #:|dotimes-count-1075|))
    (GO #:|dotimes-end-tag1080|)))
```

Above is a part of the macro expansion of the `dotimes` construct. As you can see it first increments the variable and then tests for `>=`. Thus it exits when `I` is `>=` 10. Thus the last value of `I` is `10`. Later after exiting the `dotimes` you are retrieving the value of `I` and then it's `10`.

Comment: It seems to me this behavior has actually nothing to do with iteration tools, but with the lambdas. Please see my update

Comment: But why i get 5 (or in your dotimes case 10) although the last value has been 1- that?

Comment: @Student: maybe because the particular  implementation counts up and terminates on = 10? That's a detail. Don't depend on it. If you want to see what an implementation does, you can always check the source code or see the macro expansion of a form.